# Joomla - Where do {} brackets work?

Tags: joomla

Just a simple question - aside from articles, where do {} (replacement tags?) work on Joomla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it depends on both the plug-in and the content type as to whether or not a replacement tags are acted on.

The first part is that the content type (component/modules) has to trigger the event type the plugin belongs to. Not all content types do it automatically, some for example have a setting per item (e.g. modules have a "Prepare Content" setting).

[image: Joomla 3 Prepare content option for Custom HTML Modules]

Finally, the plugin may test the content type and exclude itself from anything it doesn't recognise, or may only work on `com_content` i.e. standard Joomla articles.

Answer (score 2):

These `{}` tags work in all content systems which parse text. So modules, articles and other content components which display text.